# TabControl with ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, tabcontrol

I have a [`TabControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol.aspx) where each `TabItem` shows a [`ListView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview.aspx).
The list is the same for each tab, but it is sorted by different fields depending on the tab selected.

So, **I don't want** that each `TabItem` contains a different `ListView`:

```
<TabControl>

    <TabItem>
        <ListView/>
    </TabItem>

    <TabItem>
        <ListView/>
    </TabItem>

</TabControl>
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: "So, I don't want that each TabItem contains a different ListView" - why not? there shouldn't be any overhead, so keep it simple and direct.

Comment: Not sure if i understand your question. But you can put the ListView into a DataTemplate and put a ContentControl into the TabItem, now the ContentControl just uses the created DataTemplate as its ContentTemplate. That way you can reuse the definition of the listview. Obviously it can't be the same.

Comment: Am I sure? Not 100% but I would expect binding to only happen on the Visible tab. At least WinForms is quite smart about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and Easy. Let the code just the way it is now. Then have just one list on your ViewModel and you can have N diferent readonly properties (where N is the number of tabs) who will return the same list but sorted by your desired order.

The thing is:

> I don't want that each TabItem contains a different ListView

But that's precisely what you're doing. Having a sorted-different list within each TabItem.

**Example**

View:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SortedByX}" />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SortedByY}" />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SortedByZ}" />
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

ViewModel:

```
public List<The type of your list items> List { get; set; }

public List<The type of your list items> SortedByX 
{
    get
    {
        return List.Sort(iComparer);
    }
}

// Or using LINQ

public List<The type of your list items> SortedByY 
{
    get
    {
        return List.OrderBy....
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you make an example to clarify what you mean?